# Stored procedure - cancel where-condition depending on input

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, conditional-statements

I have a stored procedure with three input variables: @StartDate, @EndDate) and @Type:

```
select t2.ID,
    t1.DESC  
from(select ID 
      from  [dbo].[RI]
       where [Date] between @StartDate and @EndDate) t2
       left join [dbo].[R] t1 on t2.ID = t1.ID
       where t1.DESC = @Type
```

The problem is the last where condition. T1.DESC always has one of three possible values (type1, type2 or type3), but in some cases I want to cancel the "where-condition" so that I get all possible values, as if the where-condition was not executed. Fx if the @Type = 'all' the condition should be canceled. Any suggestion ?

Comment: Why not just add `or @type='all'` to it?

Comment: 'all' is not in the table t1

Comment: And that test isn't testing anything about `t1`. It's asking whether the `@type` variable is equal to the constant value `'all'`.

Comment: `where t1.DESC in 'type1, type2, type3'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use an IF/ELSE structure but have it call dynamic SQL if an actual parameter value for Type is given.  The problem with using an IF/ELSE structure with two regular sql expressions is that the optimizer will compile BOTH of those queries the first time the procedure is run using the parameters passed in. So you are baking in a parameter sniffing problem right off the bat.

Not so by using dynamic SQL, the optimizer will create a different plan for the dynamic SQL once you hit that side of the IF statement, assuming the plans would be different if you ran the queries in two separate procedures.

So your proc could look something like this (I did not syntax checked):

```
IF @Type <> 'ALL'

EXEC sp_executesql N'
select t2.ID,
    t1.DESC  
from(select ID 
      from  [dbo].[RI]
       where [Date] between @StartDateParm and @EndDateParam) t2
       left join [dbo].[R] t1 on t2.ID = t1.ID
       where t1.DESC = @TypeParam', N'@StartDateParm datetime,@EndDateParam datetime,@TypeParam varchar(5)', 
       @StartDateParm = @StartDate, @EndDateParam = @EndDate, @TypeParam = @Type;

ELSE
select t2.ID,
    t1.DESC  
from(select ID 
      from  [dbo].[RI]
       where [Date] between @StartDate and @EndDate) t2
       left join [dbo].[R] t1 on t2.ID = t1.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

So `t1.DESC` can contian values like `type1`, `type2` or `type3`. If you want to omit a filter, use an `OR` to rule it out.

```
WHERE
    @Type = 'all' OR t1.DESC = @Type
```

If your parameter is `all` then the `OR` will always return *true*, hence not filtering by `t1.DESC` value. If it's anything other than `all` then `t1.DESC` must match `@type`.

You can also use `IS NULL` instead of checking against a fixed value like `all`, that depends on your taste.

It might be important if this is a complex query to add `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` at the end, so you force the SQL engine to rebuild the execution plan again, considering the current value of your paramter. It's not the same to store an execution plan with a `WHERE` filter than without (that's what happens with 'all').